# How does a differential form looks like on $\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,1]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have a question in the subsection of examples in Wikipedia article on integration along fibers which says the following:

> Let $\pi :M\times [0,1] \rightarrow  M$ be an obvious projection. First assume $M=\mathbb{R} ^{n}$ with coordinates $x_{j}$ and consider a $k$-form:
> $$\alpha =f dx_{i_{1}}\wedge ...\wedge dx_{i_{k}}+g dt \wedge dx_{j_{1}}\wedge ... \wedge dx_{j_{k-1}}$$.
> Why does a differential form $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,1] $ has the above form ? In particular I don't understand how $dt \wedge dx_i$ is defined ?

Comment: Note that $M\times [0,1]$ or $\mathbb R^n\times [0,1]$ are manifolds with boundary, with coordinates $(x_1, \cdots, x_n, t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mainly in issue of notation, I think:
Firstly $\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then a $k$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,1]$ can written w.r.t. to a basis of the space of $k$-vectors, hence
$$\alpha = \sum_{\ell} \alpha_{\ell} dx_{\ell_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_{\ell_k}.$$
Since we usually have linearity, we only take a look at one of the summands and try to write down what could happen.
Since we like to emphasise the variable connected to $[0,1]$ we call it $t$ instead of $x_{n+1}$. Then in $dx_{\ell_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_{\ell_k}$ this $dx_{n+1}=dt$ can appear or it may not appear. To reflect both cases, we write down two summands:
$$fdx_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_{i_k}+gdx_{n+1}\wedge dx_{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_{j_{k−1}}.$$
Note that here $i_1,\ldots,i_k, j_1,\ldots,j_{k-1}\neq n+1$. Since we set $x_{n+1}=t$ we replace $dx_{n+1}=dt$ and then you have your desired form.

Also $dt\wedge dx_i$ is thereby defined as $dx_{n+1}\wedge dx_i$. Hope this helps.